# tableview returns error (datasource must return a cell)

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to update my app to iOS 7 but allot of things just disappeared or don't work anymore :S.

I cant figure this problem out, i dont know why it returns NULL.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";


NSDictionary *naamInfo;

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    naamInfo = [self.filteredNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    naamInfo = [self.nameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}



UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if ([[naamInfo objectForKey:@"gender" ] isEqual: @"man"] ) {

        cell = [UITableViewCell configureFlatCellWithColor:[UIColor peterRiverColor] selectedColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier inTableView:tableView];

    }else if ([[naamInfo objectForKey:@"gender" ] isEqual: @"woman"]){
        cell = [UITableViewCell configureFlatCellWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.396 blue:0.604 alpha:1]  selectedColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier2 inTableView:tableView];

    }

NSLog(@"CELL %@",cell);

    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:14];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.cornerRadius = 8.f; 
    cell.separatorHeight = 1.f; 

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:18];
cell.textLabel.text = [naamInfo objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [naamInfo objectForKey:@"country"];

return cell;

}
```

The log returns a NULL so i understand why i get the exception, what i dont get is how can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put:

```
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
```

after:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeue....
```

Comment: still the same problem :S

Comment: If you're using storyboard check if File's Owner is your tableVieController and if the cell is correctly set.

Comment: i checked it, i reverted back to older library and it works again, something is broken it MAKES the cell nill after i configureFlat etc... thanks for your help :)